# In which wordpress folder shall I copy an xml file to prevent unauthorized access?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to save an xml file which it should be accessed from my first plugin only. In which wordpress folder shall I save it?

I use plesk platform and If I remove permission rights of (other) not to READ plugin cannot see the xml

If I place it inside wp-admin and logout as admin I can access the URL

Shouldnt wp-admin was not accessible?

Comment: If you want it to be inaccessible from the web, as in visiting the URL, you can add a `.htaccess` file to whichever folder you wish to protect and write the appropriate code to do just that. If you're using cPanel, there is a tool that does that for you: search for Advanced -> Indexes. Go to the folder you want to protect by clicking the icons. When you find it, click on its name and you'll have to choose "No Indexing", then click on Save. You're done. Your plugin will still be able to access it because it's run by the server's user that created the file.

Comment: If I put it in wp-content am I covered? or it is risky?

Comment: Let's make something clear, it doesn't matter where you put it, it is somehow risky. **But** adding this indexing option, **you'll make sure** that, for example, if I go to `yoursite.com/path/to/your/file.xml` I'll get the following error: `403 Forbidden`. You can be sure that's going to happen. The only way you won't get the 403 error is by accessing the file from the server. And if you also want to protect the file from other plugins (or files in general) that are stored on your server, you need to use permissions (regular chmod).

Comment: Thats sound great but I dont have cPanel I have Plesk which command should I type inside htaccess and where?

Comment: Actually, it's pretty short: `Options -Indexes`. That's all you have to write in the `.htaccess` file. And save it inside the folder you want to protect. This will also be applied to all sub-folders and sub-files.

Comment: Let me know if that solves your problem, and if it doesn't, let me know what's not working! Also, remember it's a hidden file, do not forget the dot at the beginning of the file name (it has no name, only extension).

Comment: As I told you I have plesk I try <Files myfile.xml>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files> at the end of root htaccess will this do the job?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180152/discussion-between-zeke-and-maria-georgali).

Comment: The next thing I'd check is if the root `.htaccess` file is somehow preventing the new one in the plugin's folder from working. I'll be checking regularly to see if this is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of tests the following seems to work properly.I put the file in root folder and in htaccess I add the following. I allow myself to access, block all others and I allow access to server..

```
<Files myfile.xml>  
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 Allow from my_static_ip
 Allow from plesk_static_ip
</Files
```